# remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, desktop-application

I'm getting this error asking me to add BodyStyle property while I already have it in my webinvoke.

Error:
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
Operation 'ping' of contract 'IService1' specifies multiple request body parameters to be serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter can be serialized without wrapper elements. Either remove the extra body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.
Here is my service contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "ping/{pNo},{cno}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string ping(string pNo,string cno);
```

I'm calling it in my c# desktop app like so:

```
    Greenlines.Service1Client service = new Greenlines.Service1Client();
            service.ping("1", "2");
```

My app.config ServiceModel is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings> 
<client>
  <endpoint 
    address="http://192.168.100.116/WcfService/Service1.svc"
    binding="webHttpBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
    contract="Greenlines.IService1" 
    behaviorConfiguration="MyWebb"
    name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" />
</client>
<behaviors>

<endpointBehaviors>

<behavior name="MyWebb">

<webHttp />

</behavior>

</endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors> 
</system.serviceModel>
```

P.S. Service works fine in browser/postman and also in android application client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we have set up the configuration on the server-side. But there is a common ground between the invocation to Restful service and the invocation to SOAP service when we call the service by a client proxy. that is, we should keep the service contract consistent between the server-side and the client-side. Thereby please consider adding the below code segments to the automatically generated service contract on the client-side.
**Reference.cs.**

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetDataResponse")]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ping/{value1}，{value2}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData(string value1, string value2);
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.